# pass func as arg to another func in tradingview's pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

trying to pass a func as an arg to another func...

```
1  //@version=5
2  indicator("My script")
3
4  f1() => 1
5  f2() => f1()
7    
8  // accept func as arg
9  f3() => 2
10 f4(func) =>
11     func()
12 
13 out1 = f2()
14 out2 = f4(f3)
15
16 if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
17     label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(out1)) // returns 1 
18     label.new(bar_index, low, str.tostring(out2))  // returns error (see below)
```

gives error:
`Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 11: Could not find function or function reference 'func'.`
is there a way to accomplish this? thx!

Comment: i guess i would never *need* to do this since all functions belong to the global scope. https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/User-defined_functions.html?highlight=scope#scopes-in-the-script

Comment: You cannot do this and you don't need to as you said.